# Having one javascript load multiple other javascripts without touching the <head>

Tags: javascript

I'm working for a company right now that has hundreds of pages that use a javascript to load a left sidebar. I didn't create the original, but have to work within its framework. I;m fairly new to Java, want to insert a new image slideshow (from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm) into the this sidebar. Unfortunately, I need to load 3 other javascript files in this one, as well as create a div with the javascript for my slideshow to go in. I spent 6 hours on it today, trying multiple solutions I've found on this site and others, couldn't get it to work.

Is this possible?

I need to load "javaA.js", "javaB.js", & "javaC.js" from this script, which runs on over 500 pages. Part 2 is having a div created, but just this first part would help heaps.

Thanks in advance for help.

Solution Found:

Here's the code that ended up working for me:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)

if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
loadjscssfile("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "js")
loadjscssfile("JavaA.js", "js")
loadjscssfile("JavaB.js", "js")
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery? If not, you cannot use $('head').append, but document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<script ...></script>'

Comment: Do not confuse java with javascript. Those are two totally different things.

Comment: This bit of code is from when I was just throwing anything in there in frustration. I've been trying the getElements approach, but not sure how to add multiple instances of code using the code you and MrCode provided

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, where the script element is created and then appended to the `head` dynamically:

```
var headElem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://www.site.com/file.js';

headElem.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Would I repeat this multiple times for each script, or add a new line in this code. like this
    var headElem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://www.site.com/file.js';
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://www.site.com/file2.js';
headElem.appendChild(newScript);

Comment: @Justin, yes you can repeat it for multiple scripts, you don't need to repeat the first line though, that only needs to be defined once. If you're going to repeat this lots of times, you could create a simple function that accepts the script URL and does the include like `includeScript('http://site.com/script.js')`.